# installing applications in Kbunutu 18.0

Tags: software-installation

very new to the Kubuntu, I cannot seem to understand the process of installing new applications! they all seem to go to some K place as zip files open and there seem to be no way of giving the install command. the help files are all gibberish to me, I am of course used to .exe files or zip files that open and give that option after the package is opened. HELP!